Origin header missing on API call outside of network using Azure
I was getting a CORS error.  I reviewed the spec and sure enough, my requests outside the network were missing the "origin" header.
And then in network you can see the origin header

So I need help troubleshooting why the header "Origin" is getting stripped by Azure

True in this case; I posted that comment a bit too quickly. Apologies. I've deleted the comment and reversed my downvote.

It ended up being radware, which is a bot manager type deal.  If anyone ever runs into this, the key is to do an OPTIONS request from outside the network.  I did that in POSTMAN and then the radware response page came up.  You should normally see 404 with an OPTIONS request, since there's no endpoint specifically assigned to that method usually.  Check that your firewall allows OPTIONS requests in this circumstance.

The Origin header is set by the browser, so this is not something 'Azure' can strip.
The header will not be set if the origin matches the URL you're opening.

I think you're right...we used to use the azure name for the API but now they have the same origin.  Going to verify a bit more and then check this as correct
